# Баг с событиями на табе "Репутация"

Tags: дефект, репутация

На вкладке [Репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=reputation) неправильно отображаются детали событий за один вопрос, если события наступили в разное время:

[image: События]

Т.е. всего событий за "вывод записей через WHERE" - 3. Одно событие наступило через час после двух других.

Краткая информация разделяет эти события на две группы (2 события + 1 событие), но когда смотрим детали двух событий, то видим уже 3 события.

Т.е. здесь логично было бы отображать только те события, которые учтены в краткой информации.

Comment: +1, но это лучше на [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/), потому что скорее всего, такое бывает на всех сайтах.

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести, а в [вашей истории изменений репутации](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5079/bopoh?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=3) тоже больше нет этой ошибки. Сообщайте, если снова встретите.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, надо смотреть недавние голоса, т.к. старые вроде группируются и поэтому такой проблемы там нет. У меня редко рейтинг меняется, поэтому сам я не скоро смогу посмотреть )